# c++ program to check the frequencies of the letters

Tags: c++

I am writing a c++ program to check the frequencies of the letters. When the output has no space like "aabbbsssd", my code can exactly check the frequencies of the letters. However, if the input has space like: "do be do bo." my output just
"d 1" and "o 1", no frequencies of "b" and "e".

#### Updated code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Letters
{
  Letters() : freq(0){}
  Letters(char letter,int freq) {
    this->freq = freq;
    this->letter = letter;
}
char letter;
int freq;
};

bool Greater(const Letters& a, const Letters& b)
{
   if(a.freq == b.freq)
      return a.letter < b.letter;

   return a.freq > b.freq;
}

int main () {

cout<<"Enter text:" << endl;
string input;
getline(cin, input);

vector<Letters> count;
int letters[26]= {0};

for (int x = 0; x < input.length(); x++) {
    if (isalpha(input[x])) {
        int c = tolower(input[x] - 'a');
        letters[c]++;
    }
}

for (int x = 0; x < 26; x++) {
    if (letters[x] > 0) {
        char c = x + 'a';
        count.push_back(Letters(c, letters[x]));
    }
}

std::sort(count.begin(),count.end(),Greater);

cout<<"Frequencies:" << endl;
for (int x = 0 ; x < count.size(); x++) {
    cout<<count[x].letter <<  " " << count[x].freq<<"\n";
  }


return 0;
}
```

Apologies if this is written poorly, and thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What did you observe when inspecting your code with the debugger?

Comment: The former `if` statement `if(a >'a' && a<='z')` doesn't seem harmful, but doesn't seem useful.

Comment: Not only that, but `a - 'a'` assumes that the letters are contiguous (i.e. no other characters between `'a'` and `'z'`).   This is true for some character sets (e.g. ASCII) but not others.

Comment: Are you sure there will be no upper case input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update

Assuming that the persons who test your program also enter uppercase text, your program should look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int alpha[26] = {0};

int main(void)
{
    string text;

    cout << "Enter text:" << endl;
    getline(cin, text);

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        int a = text[i];

        if (a >= 'A' && a <= 'Z')
        {
            alpha[a - 'A']++;
        }
        else if (a >= 'a' && a <= 'z')
        {
            alpha[a - 'a']++;
        }
    }

    cout << "Frequencies:" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (alpha[i])
        {
            cout << right << char('a' + i) << setw(2) << right << alpha[i] << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I submit for testing, it shows me this kind of errors {https://submit.cs.ucsb.edu/submission/203516}. Is it the problem on setw?

Comment: You are only reading the first "do" of "do be do be". That is the entire problem. Read the entire line and then start counting. Setw is not your problem. You could have discovered this yourself if you had debugged or just displayed the string you just had read from cin.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ioV3j.png, I make it like an image. May be you can take a look for it.

Comment: That looks like a review. Could you post your updated code somewhere?

Comment: But when I submit to test, it has some errors like the image I show you.

Comment: It works fine here. FWIW, you can omit the first `if` and change the second one to: `if (a >= 'a' && a <= 'z')` (assuming you only receive lower case text -- otherwise you'll have to handle `'A'` through `'Z'` as well).

Comment: @pansoh: see my update. That works for me. I checked the results (counted the frequencies) manually.

Comment: I am doing the same thing as you. But when I submit to test, it catches some errors like the image show:        http://i.stack.imgur.com/M9WMB.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LTwxC.png
  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/RC0Tg.png

Comment: I don't know where are the errors come from. If I can't fix it, I can not get the full credit.

Comment: Ok,there are a few problems. The sorted test expects the output to be sorted by frequency. And your output using "right" and " setw" can be simplified: "cout << char('a' + i) << " " << alpha[i] << endl;"

Comment: @pansoh: But why am I guessing? Didn't you get any specifications for the expected output? It is hard to tell what the code should look like if you don't know the specs. And this is going way beyond the original question. Update it with the specs **in text format**, not some images.

Comment: on the left hand side for the image is the expect output, right hand side is my output. Because I submit my code to a test program to test where is right or not. So is difficult to do a text format. Sorry!

Comment: @pansoh: Yes, but how do you know what kind of output they expect? There must be specifications, no matter in which form.

Comment: For the problem, the expect output is the one which we do manually, is absolutely correct. However, when I submit to the test program, the expect output for the test program is the one show on the left hand side in the image. I also have no idea why the two expect outputs are different.

Comment: No it is not correct. What are the specifications? I am sure they don't expect you to guess.

Comment: Do you mind I screenshot the problem to you? I am not very sure after I read several times for the problem. I think is the order. They want the frequencies like from the most to the least.

Comment: Yeah , post a link.

Comment: @pansoh: Ok, that is a spec to work with. You can not just store the frequencies is an array you index by character, you must sort them by frequency. Sortibg such an array would lose the association between letter and frequency. So either your output routine needs more work ,or you need a better data type (e.g. a pair) and a way to do a stable sort for frequency. But that is you r assignment, so you should write it. If you have **specific** problems, ask about them in a new question. Your original question was answered.

Comment: @pansoh: one tip: read the spec carefully. Put the problems in a list and solve them one by one. Think about the data types you will need, and how you solve each item in your list. Your program only fulfills some of these problems. Split your program into functions, each of which solve one item in your spec list, in other words: split the spec into simpler subproblems and solve them one by one. **Good luck**.

Comment: I made it in order this time. But still fails. I have updated my code. May be you can take a look. This time I solved it in order.

Comment: @pansoh: <sigh> It is your assigment. Where is the updated code? Did you fulfill the other specs too?

Comment: I think so. I double check that I meet the specs.

Comment: If I enter `The quick BROWN fox jumped over the lazy dog.`, then I get `e 4`, `o 3`, etc..., but that string contains 4 letters `o` (in brown, fox, over, dog). So you still have a problem.

Comment: @pansoh: I am not a free debugging service. You could at least upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: @pansoh: I found the error. Let's see if you can find it too.

Comment: @pansoh: [help on upvoting and accepting an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I think the error is my code does not check the frequencies of capital letters.

Comment: @pansoh: Your error is that you do `tolower(... - 'a')`, but what you need is `tolower(...) - 'a'`.

Comment: Do I need to add one toupper function to include the capital?

Comment: @pansoh: no, because the spec says that 'A'` and `'a'` should be counted as the same. `tolower('A')` returns `'a'`, and `tolower('a')` returns `'a'`too, and that is exactly what the spec says. Try it. Run your improved program, enter a long string and manually count to check the results.

Comment: @pansoh: From here on, you should be able to handle it on your own. I think I helped enough.

Comment: I completely solved the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`cin >> text;` will read only until the first whitespace character after the first non-whitespace character.

You can use [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read a whole line like this:

```
getline(cin, text);
```

Comment: Thanks! I fix it already. When I submit it to test, I meet some errors like the image show {i.stack.imgur.com/ioV3j.png}. I am not sure how to fix it. Can you give me some ideas?

Comment: What is the specification? Shouldn't upper case letters be counted? Shouldn't there be a space between alphabet and number? Sholdn't the output be sorted? To fix it, modify your code to match the specification.

Answer (score 0):

Well, cin will only read in until space delimiter and to read in the whole line, you need to use getline(cin, v); where v is the variable you want put the input inside.